# How to create Survey my webpage without any back-end data hosted at my server

Tags: html, survey

Is there any free survey tool which provides API calls to store survey data and generate reports? so that I can create online survey on my web page and get reports from that online free tool?

Answer (score 0):

LimeSurvey : https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API Free like a beer and a speech.